# How to modify AvalonDock NavigatorWindow

Tags: wpf, avalondock, sharpdevelop

I am using `AvalonDock` as the docking manager for my application. I noticed that it has a Ctrl + Tab window (the `NavigatorWindow`) but that seems to have some odd hard-coded classifications. I switched my last `LayoutAnchorable` to a `LayoutDocument`, so at least I don't have things in different groups now, but I really don't need "Active Tool Windows" and "Active Files" doesn't make sense in my context.

Is there any way to customize this component? I'd ideally just like to hide the left list, and change the tile of the right list to something more generic like "Active Windows".

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

There is a style that you can override (see below). The [NavigatorWindow](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/wiki/Window-Class-Diagram) itself has no dependency properties that you could use to configure it so I don't think you can do more than restyling - but maybe thats all you need :-)

```
xmlns:avalonDockControls="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Controls"

              <Style x:Key="{x:Type avalonDockControls:NavigatorWindow}"
                     TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:NavigatorWindow}">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                <Setter Property="SizeToContent"
                        Value="WidthAndHeight" />
                <Setter Property="ResizeMode"
                        Value="NoResize" />
                <Setter Property="shell:WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <shell:WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness="10"
                                        CaptionHeight="16"
                                        CornerRadius="3,3,3,3"
                                        GlassFrameThickness="4" />
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:NavigatorWindow}">
                      <Grid>
                        <Border x:Name="WindowBorder"
                                BorderThickness="3"
                                Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}">
                          <Grid Margin="5">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                              <RowDefinition MinHeight="54" />
                              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                              <RowDefinition MinHeight="42" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid>
                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                              <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                  <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding SelectedDocument.LayoutElement.IconSource, Converter={StaticResource NullToDoNothingConverter}}"
                                       Stretch="None">
                                </Image>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="selectedElementTitle"
                                           Text="{Binding SelectedDocument.LayoutElement.Title}"
                                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                           Margin="4,0,0,0">
                                </TextBlock>
                              </Grid>
                              <TextBlock x:Name="selectedElementDescription"
                                         Text="{Binding SelectedDocument.LayoutElement.Description}"
                                         TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center">
                              </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <Grid Margin="5">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                  <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="Active Tool Windows"
                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                           Margin="0,3,0,4">
                                </TextBlock>
                                <ListBox x:Name="PART_AnchorableListBox"
                                         Grid.Row="1"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Anchorables}"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAnchorable, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                         Background="Transparent"
                                         BorderThickness="0"
                                         MaxHeight="400"
                                         FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
                                  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                      <Setter Property="Cursor"
                                              Value="Hand" />
                                      <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                                 Value="True">
                                          <Setter Property="Background"
                                                  Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                                          <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                                                  Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                      </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                      <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                          <ColumnDefinition />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding LayoutElement.IconSource, Converter={StaticResource NullToDoNothingConverter}}"
                                               Stretch="None">
                                        </Image>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LayoutElement.Title}"
                                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                   Margin="4,2,0,2">
                                        </TextBlock>
                                      </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                              </Grid>
                              <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="5">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                  <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="Active Files"
                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                           Margin="0,3,0,4">
                                </TextBlock>
                                <ListBox x:Name="PART_DocumentListBox"
                                         Grid.Row="1"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDocument, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                         Background="Transparent"
                                         BorderThickness="0"
                                         MaxHeight="400"
                                         FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
                                  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                      <Setter Property="Cursor"
                                              Value="Hand" />
                                      <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                                 Value="True">
                                          <Setter Property="Background"
                                                  Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                                          <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                                                  Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                      </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                      <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                          <ColumnDefinition />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding LayoutElement.IconSource, Converter={StaticResource NullToDoNothingConverter}}"
                                               Stretch="None">
                                        </Image>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LayoutElement.Title}"
                                                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                                   Margin="4,2,0,2">
                                        </TextBlock>
                                      </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                      <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                </ListBox>
                              </Grid>
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDocument.LayoutElement.ToolTip}"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center">
                              </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                          </Grid>
                        </Border>
                      </Grid>
                      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="SelectedDocument"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                          <Setter Property="Text"
                                  Value="{Binding SelectedAnchorable.LayoutElement.Title}"
                                  TargetName="selectedElementTitle" />
                          <Setter Property="Text"
                                  Value="{x:Null}"
                                  TargetName="selectedElementDescription" />
                        </Trigger>
                      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully I can use that to hide the parts I don't want and rename the parts I want to keep.